# Plot Title/Annotation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, macos, core-plot

I want to add a title to my graph that gives a short description or name about the plot. For example, I have a table with a list of products and my graph shows how much those products cost. There should be a label/annotation superimposed on the graph that gives the name of the product.

Answer (score 0):

Create a UILabel, set it's text, and add it as a subview of the graph view.

Comment: Actually, you don't want to set it as a subview, because we invert the coordinate space of things drawn within the graph.  Setting it as a sibling view that is positioned above the graph should do the trick.

Comment: Fair enough, sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

**Brad** -- siblings inside of which type of View exactly? 
In the `CPTestApp`, I took the `BarChart NIB` and placed both the `CPLayerHostingView` and a `UILabel` (for the Plot title) into a generic `UIView` (making them children of the `UIView`). The graph showed up, but the label did not. How do I get the label to show?

**EDIT:** 
I figured it out with this line -- 
in `CPTestAPP`, change

```
CPLayerHostingView *hostingView = (CPLayerHostingView *)self.view;
```

to

```
CPLayerHostingView *hostingView = (CPLayerHostingView *)layerView;
```

where `layerView` is your `UIView` (with class `CPLayerHostingView` -- make sure to set this in `IB`) that is contained inside of a generic `UIView`. That generic `UIView` can have all the `UILabels` you want as children. woohoo!

**Graph with label here:**

[Sample Here](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?80ef43717f.png)